# Rails nested route using :only. How to also add extra routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently I have the routes below.

Routes

```
resources :applications do 
  resources :jobseeker, :only=> [:index, :new, :create]
end

get 'jobseeker/load' => 'jobseeker#load'
post 'jobseeker/retrieve' => 'jobseeker#retrieve'
```

They produce urls like this:

```
/applications/1/jobseeker/index
/applications/1/jobseeker/new
/applications/1/jobseeker/create
/jobseeker/load
/jobseeker/retrieve
```

But what i want is to have urls like this:

```
/applications/1/jobseeker/index
/applications/1/jobseeker/new
/applications/1/jobseeker/create
/applications/1/jobseeker/load
/applications/1/jobseeker/retrieve
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
resources :applications do 
  resources :jobseeker, :only=> [:index, :new, :create] do
    collection do
      get  :load
      post :retrieve
    end
  end
end
```